# Ping specific IP range is not working in Mac

Tags: macos, ping, hosts, hosts-file

I have edit my `/etc/hosts` file as below. I am new to mac Os and try to run some codes and test. for that i have to edit `/etc/hosts` file. But ping for IPs not working as expected. please help me to understand the issue.

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       198.18.0.98
127.0.0.1       70.70.70.70
127.0.0.1       nipuna.lk
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

`ping nipuna.lk` works fine.  `ping 70.70.70.70` takes 300-400ms but ping works. but `ping 198.18.0.98` is not working. I do not know why this is happening.

My firewall is turned off.

```
macOs Big Sur
version 11.2.3 (20D91)
```

```
ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:de:48:00:11:22 
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:e9:fe:87:df:7a 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 88:e9:fe:87:df:7a 
    inet6 fe80::808:35e:834f:b528%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.1.4 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 9e:68:c9:36:de:63 
    inet6 fe80::9c68:c9ff:fe36:de63%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 9e:68:c9:36:de:63 
    inet6 fe80::9c68:c9ff:fe36:de63%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:23:8d:28:44:01 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:23:8d:28:44:00 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:23:8d:28:44:05 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:23:8d:28:44:04 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:23:8d:28:44:01 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 12 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::22d9:6676:ea11:6a32%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xe 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::fbf9:4cfd:3512:fa43%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Comment: You can't use /etc/hosts to alias one IP to another. It's for translating names to IPs.

Comment: @JimStewart , I have edited `/etc/hosts` many ways. But did not work for anyway.
tried `127.0.0.1       198.18.0.98` , `localhost      198.18.0.98`, `198.18.0.98 localhost` ,  `198.18.0.98   127.0.0.1` but none of these are working.